# bind(this) in ReactJS and onChange update to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

index.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            homeLink: "Home"
        };
    }

    onGreet() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }

    onChangeLinkName(newName) {
        this.setState({
            homeLink: newName
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <Header homeLink={this.state.homeLink}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <Home
                            name={"Max"}
                            initialAge={27}
                            greet={this.onGreet}
                            changeLink={this.onChangeLinkName.bind(this)}
                            initialLinkName={this.state.homeLink}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And
Home.js

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            age: props.initialAge,
            status: 0,
            homeLink: props.initialLinkName
        };
    }

    onMakeOlder() {
        this.setState({
            age: this.state.age + 3
        });
    }

    onChangeLink() {
        this.props.changeLink(this.state.homeLink);
    }

    onHandleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            homeLink: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>In a new Component!</p>
                <p>Your name is {this.props.name}, your age is {this.state.age}</p>
                <p>Status:  {this.state.status}</p>
                <hr/>
                <button onClick={() => this.onMakeOlder()} className="btn btn-primary">Make me older!</button>
                <hr/>
                <button onClick={this.props.greet} className="btn btn-primary">Greet</button>
                <hr/>
                <input type="text" value ={this.state.homeLink}
                       onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)}/>
                <button onClick={this.onChangeLink.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary">Change Header Link</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Would `onChange` in the `input` tag be triggered as soon as I write something in the `input` field and update to `state`? I can't see the `state` change in the `React Developer Tool` extension in Chrome when I write something in the `input` field.

When I click the button `this.onChangeLink` it triggers the `onChangeLink` function. The `onChangeLink` doesn't seem to take any arguments since the brakets are empty, still I'm able to pass `this.state.homeLink` to `this.props.changeLink` inside the `onChangeLink` function. `this.props.changeLink` which is also a function in `index.js` takes an argument `newName`. I guess this is where the `bind(this)` comes in. What does `bind(this)` do? Could I rewrite it with a fat arrow function like `(event) => this.onChangeLink(event)`?

Comment: yes you definitely can represent it with an arrow function, the arrow function does the binding for you, also you can just write as `onChange={this.handleChange}` and further represent the handlechange function as, `handleChange = (e) => { ... }` here the `this` gets bound automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is a function in `Function.prototype` which returns a function object which is bound to the current `this`.

```
onClick={this.onChangeLink.bind(this)}
```

Here `onClick` function will be passed as a handler  with the current context.

An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) does not create a new `this` context at all. The `this` will refer to the context in which the function is *defined*.

> An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has its original meaning from the enclosing context.

```
onChange={(event) => this.onChangeLink(event)}
```

Here even though `onChangeLink` is not bound, it is called within an arrow function within the same `this` context.

So.. yes, you can replace it with a fat arrow notation to get the same effect. Although you have to rewrite the list of arguments in this case twice.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to `onChangeLink` in `Home` component. You can directly pass the value to `App` component.

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            age: props.initialAge,
            status: 0,
            homeLink: props.initialLinkName
        };
    }

    onMakeOlder() {
        this.setState({
            age: this.state.age + 3
        });
    }

    onHandleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            homeLink: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
    
        return (
            <div>
                
                <input type="text" value ={this.state.homeLink}
                       onChange={(event) => this.onHandleChange(event)}/>
                <button onClick={()=>this.props.changeLink(this.state.homeLink)} className="btn btn-primary">Change Header Link</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            homeLink: "Home"
        };
    }

    onGreet() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }

    onChangeLinkName(newName) {
        this.setState({
            homeLink: newName
        });
    }

    render() {
    console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                        <Home
                            name={"Max"}
                            initialAge={27}
                            greet={this.onGreet}
                            changeLink={this.onChangeLinkName.bind(this)}
                            initialLinkName={this.state.homeLink}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very helpful. Sorry I can only mark one as correct.

Comment: I tested to also rewrite `changeLink={this.onChangeLinkName.bind(this)}` to `changeLink ={(event) => this.onChangeLinkName(event)}` and it works well. Any issues with rewriting like this?